# how to copy a file to another file in separate directories?

Tags: command-line, 16.04, ssh, files, copy

So I have created to vm's with the ubuntu 16.04 version. I'm trying to copy my public key into the authorized_keys file, how I have done this is with the command `cp id_rsa.pub home/vagrant/.ssh/` I done the command from the home/deploy/.ssh/ directory but I get the following error: `cp: cannot create regular file 'home/vagrant/.ssh/': No such file or directory`. Can anyone tell me why I'm getting this error.

Thank you for the help in advance.

Comment: Because `home/vagrant/.ssh/` is a *relative path* (relative to the directory in which you are executing the command). You likely need the *absolute path* `/home/vagrant/.ssh/`

Comment: [Ubuntu 16.04 LTS has reached the end of it's *standard* support life](https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2021/03/13/extended-security-maintenance-for-ubuntu-16-04-xenial-xerus-begins-april-30-2021/) thus is now off-topic here unless your question is specific to helping you move to a supported release of Ubuntu.  Ubuntu 16.04 ESM support is available, but not on-topic here, see https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic  See also https://ubuntu.com/blog/ubuntu-16-04-lts-transitions-to-extended-security-maintenance-esm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The command fails because you need a forward slash at the start of the path, like this:

```
cp id_rsa.pub /home/vagrant/.ssh/
```

In order to actually use the key, you can add the key to `authorized_keys` with this command:

```
cat id_rsa.pub >> /home/vagrant/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

Comment: thanks for the help that seemed to work now I'm getting permission denied so I done the command as the root user and it seemed to copy fine just need the authorized_keys file if it actually copied into it.